# What would be the level curves of the complex exponential function $e^z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So by definition, let $z = x + iy$, $e^z = e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y$.
Then we set $e^x \cos y $ and $e^x \sin y$ to be constant,
what would be the level curves for those two functions.
(I tried to graph those function in GeoGebra, but it didn't make much sense to me)

This is an exercise problem from Gamelin's complex analysis at page 61.
Also what would be the level curves for the function $e^{\alpha z}$ where $\alpha$ is a complex number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily draw the level curves of the real and imaginary parts of $e^{x+iy}$. Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5BRe%5BExp%5Bx+%2B+I+y%5D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D) and  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5BIm%5BExp%5Bx+%2B+I+y%5D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D).